# Django Function Base View Search Form By Primary Key

Tags: python, django

The code sample as novice of Django, is it right practice to achieve page load per ID as shown below?

## View.py

```
def testidbasesearch(request,id=None):
    if request.method == "GET":
        print ('Inside IF GET')
        if not id:
            form = MtiForiegnForm()
        else:
            instance = Mt_Issue_foriegn.objects.get(id=id)
            form = MtiForiegnForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    else:
        print ('Inside Else GET')
        id=request.POST.get('pkid')
        return redirect(reverse('testidbasesearch', kwargs={"id": id}))      
    return render(request,'testingpost.html',{'form':form})
```

## url.py

```
path('testidbasesearch',testidbasesearch,name='testidbasesearch'),
path('testidbasesearch/<int:id>',testidbasesearch,name='testidbasesearch'),
```

## testingpost.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


<form id="postform1" method="post"  action="">
{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="pkid" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit-form" />
        {% for form1 in form %}
     <fieldset disabled="disabled">
        {{ form1 }}
      </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
     </form>
{% endblock %}
```

First of all  my functionality is working as expected , I just need review is it right code practice, I purposely avoid AJAX/jquery ( i.e. js) pure django /python code to load form based on id submitted.

Comment: Does does "achieve page load per id" mean?

Comment: many application issue some ticket number,  so in above example pkid is sort of ticket number , so if some one has pkid ( ticket number) they can submit and get the information about particular record.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @dirkgroten just got to know about codereview after your response..